# How to use svmpredict in matlab?

Tags: machine-learning, label, svm, libsvm, predict

[predicted_label, accuracy, decision_values/prob_estimates] = svmpredict(testing_label_vector, testing_instance_matrix, model [, 'libsvm_options']);

**1. I am using libsvm for image classification in matlab. What does
    testing_label_vector, testing_instance_matrix, decision_values/prob_estimates, most importantly, accuracy in "svmpredict"
    mean?**

**2. If I am using it for testing to obtain accuracy value, Do I have to
    know the values for testing_label_vector?**

Answer (score 1):

(1)

- `testing_label`: are the true labels of the data on which you want to test
- `testing_instance_matrix`: is the data on which you want to test, one per row. The label of each data point is in testing_label.
- `decision_values`: are the decision values
- `accuracy`: is what percentage of the predicted labels agrees with the real labels

(2)

Yes. You certainly need ground truth to compute accuracy.

Comment: Should the same testimage label be different for different models(In multiclass SVM) ?